# How to filter array table in ng-zorro table?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm new to Angular.

I have a demo array like this:

```
for (let index = 1; index <= 100; index++) {
  this.listOfData.push([
    `Name ${index}`,
    `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`,
    'Employee',
  ]);
}
```

And I try to create a filter table with search function:

```
onSearch = (value) => {
  const output = this.listOfData.filter((arr) =>
    arr.some((item) => {
      item.toLowerCase().includes(value);
    })
  );
  console.log('output: ', output);
  this.listOfDisplayData = output;
};
```

This is my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npy1ph?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically your data item is `[[string,string,string],...]` when you start filtering with `filter` you must return `true` for it to include and `false` to filter it out.

This should fix it

```js
  onSearch = (value) => {
    const output = this.listOfData.filter((arr) =>
      arr.some((item) => {
        if (item.toLowerCase().includes(value)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
    console.log('output: ', output);
    this.listOfDisplayData = output;
  }
```

Comment: thanks you. After a short break time I also understand that it take the last item so it return false.